# The button is not visible on runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I'm working on mobile application, Java Android and I'm using Android Studio as IDE.

On the first screen (first Activity) there is no problems and the button to go to the second Activity is working well.

But I have 3 activities and I've put a button in the second Activity (to switch to the third Activity). This button is visible on design, but invisible when I run the application with Emulator. I can't understand why. Could somebody help me?

This is java file

```
package com.example.debit_cablage.controler;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.debit_cablage.R;
public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String ACTION ="com.example.SHOW_REPORT_ACTIVITY";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

    Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(arguments != null) {
        String name = arguments.get("spinner_name").toString();
        String affaire = arguments.get("spinner_affaire").toString();
        String equipe = arguments.get("spinner_equipe").toString();
        textView.setText("Vous êtes : " + name + "\nVous prenez les matériels pour le numéro d'affiare : " + affaire + "\net pour l'équipement : "+ equipe);
    }
    setContentView(textView);
}
public void onClickEditor(View view) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
}
```

And this is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.debit_cablage.controler.EditorActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="161dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:onClick="onClickEditor"
    android:text="Continuer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</Button>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: because you set a new content view to your activity, everything in your xml layout is meaningless

Comment: OK, I thought about it.. but how I can get the information from the first Activity but also have a button to go to the third Activity?
Is it possible??

Comment: yes, you just need to remove ` setContentView(textView);`

Comment: It doesn't work.. I have information from the first activity still but not my button.. :(

Comment: The problem is that I would like to keep the info taken from the first Activity and the button. But as I see I can see or the info from the first Activity or the button.. it's not cool..

Comment: Your layout only has 'Continuer' button and 'textView2', which button wasn't shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, you just have to remove the 2nd `setContentView()`
But if you want to display the retrieved information, you can use the `TextView` defined in the xml layout

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(arguments != null) {
        String name = arguments.get("spinner_name").toString();
        String affaire = arguments.get("spinner_affaire").toString();
        String equipe = arguments.get("spinner_equipe").toString();
        textView.setText("Vous êtes : " + name + "\nVous prenez les matériels pour le numéro d'affiare : " + affaire + "\net pour l'équipement : "+ equipe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! it works!!
Just changed this line:
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
on this one
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
And I can see both: the text and the button :)

Comment: And I've put awail this line:
    setContentView(textView);